# Why are pip3 packages not getting installed on a specific network?

Tags: ubuntu, pip, ubuntu-20.04

I've recently installed Ubuntu. After installation, I tried to install `pip3` packages, but they're not getting installed on my home wifi network. However, the packages are getting installed on my mobile data network and hotspot connected from another laptop.

```
pip3 install selenium
```

```
Collecting selenium
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /packages/80/d6/4294f0b4bce4de0abf13e17190289f9d0613b0a44e5dd6a7f5ca98459853/selenium-3.141.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /packages/80/d6/4294f0b4bce4de0abf13e17190289f9d0613b0a44e5dd6a7f5ca98459853/selenium-3.141.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /packages/80/d6/4294f0b4bce4de0abf13e17190289f9d0613b0a44e5dd6a7f5ca98459853/selenium-3.141.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /packages/80/d6/4294f0b4bce4de0abf13e17190289f9d0613b0a44e5dd6a7f5ca98459853/selenium-3.141.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /packages/80/d6/4294f0b4bce4de0abf13e17190289f9d0613b0a44e5dd6a7f5ca98459853/selenium-3.141.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/80/d6/4294f0b4bce4de0abf13e17190289f9d0613b0a44e5dd6a7f5ca98459853/selenium-3.141.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (Caused by ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)"))
```

Comment: did you try `sudo pip3 install selenium`?

Comment: Yes, it produces the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the answer after trying many times. The following dependencies solve the problem:
`sudo apt-get install python3 python3-dev python3-pip libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev`